# Typescript/yarn workspaces - Referenced project may not disable emit

Tags: typescript, react-native, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to setup a monorepo project using typescript and yarn workspaces.

The project's structure looks like this:

```
/example
/packages
  /lib1
```

Example is an app that used the packages, for development purposes.

When I use `yarn tsc --build --force` I get the following error:

```
example/tsconfig.json:6:18 - error TS6310: Referenced project '/packages/intro' may not disable emit.
```

Here's example's tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib"
  },
  "references": [{ "path": "../packages/intro" }]
}
```

And the one at the project's root:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "React Native",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "my-project/*": ["./packages/*/src"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "packages/*/lib",
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ],
  "references": [{ "path": "./example" }, { "path": "./packages/lib1" }]
}
```

And the lib1's tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib"
  }
}
```

As you can see I do have `noEmit` set to `true` so I don't understand what the error is about. I've tried setting the value directly in each tsconfig files but that didn't do anything as expected.

Comment: Just opened up an issue on github. May be useful for someone digging: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49844

Comment: just put `noEmit: false` inside your `packages/lib1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use either noEmit or emitDeclarationOnly fields individually without having to specify the other, to fix your issue - **try replacing noEmit with emitDeclarationOnly**, e.g:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "React Native",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true, // use this field instead of "noEmit"
    "paths": {
      "my-project/*": ["./packages/*/src"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "packages/*/lib",
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ],
  "references": [{ "path": "./example" }, { "path": "./packages/lib1" }]
}
```

sources:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmit
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#emitDeclarationOnly

Answer (score 0):

Workaround based on [zerdox's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71704754/typescript-yarn-workspaces-referenced-project-may-not-disable-emit/75718390#comment128802782_71704754):

Just add the following:

```
"files": [],
```

to your root **tsconfig.json**

Example:

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "packages/types"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: if I do that nothing happens for me, I mean tsc --noEmit just doesn't show any compile time errors and quickly exits with exit code 0

Answer (score -8):

Setting `noEmit` to `true` disables emitting, which is what the error is saying. You need to set `noEmit` to `false` to enable emitting.

Comment: what if I actually don't want emit?

Comment: It's generally necessary for packages. If you don't want the files there after the build, have a look at `--clean`.

Comment: I strictly only use `tsc` for type checking and different tools for building

Comment: Sounds like you're asking a completely unrelated question then. I'd suggest asking your own question separate to this one.

Comment: What if I am already disabled emitting? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49844 You can find repro link in this issue.

Comment: Had to vote down, yes many people want to disable emitting, not everything is distributed, most people don't distribute, answer should include this.